# Is the use of computed "include" or "required" a bad code smell?

Tags: php, configuration

Is using computed include / require a bad code smell and does it have a bad impact on the performance? And I guess that having the included file execute code is also a bad thing to do, but is it ok if that behavior is documented?

**Background information / Reason for my question:**

I need to call an API to get information about some services. I have about 50 services with each service needing to call the API for 0-6 times. So I'm looking for a way to configure

- The parameters for the API call (argumenttype differs between calls, may be a string but it also may be an array)
- Define which API to call

I thought of having a single file for each service containing the calls and return the information as a single array like this:

```php
<?php

    // Params for Call 1
    $anArrayWithSomeParams = array('param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'param4');

    // Params for Call 2
    $aString = 'string1';
    $anotherString = 'string2'

    // Params for Call 3-6
    ...

    $someInformation            = $dmy->getSomeInformation($anArrayWithSomeParams);
    $notNeededHere              = NULL;
    $moreInformation            = $dmy->getMoreInformation($aString,$anotherString);
    ...

    $allData = array( '0'   => $someInformation,
                    '1'     => $notNeededHere
                    '2'     => $tablespace,
                    ....
    );
?>
```

I then could include that file and use the variable `alldata` to access the data and do something with it like this:

```php
require_once('class.dummy.php');
$directories = array("dir1", "dir2", "dir3");
$dmy = new dummy();

foreach($directories as $path) {
    $allData = NULL;
    $executeDataCollection = $path.'myFile.php';
    require($executeDataCollection);
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($allData);
    print "</pre>";
}
```

While this might work, it does not seem like an elegant solution. I was wondering if somebody could give me a hint towards a more elegant/sophisticated way of handling this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `require` is considered bad practice. You should be using an autoloader. However, that being said, using a dynamic class name (which is how you'd do this with autoloading) is also bad practice. Usually what is done in OOP is an interface, mutliple classes that implement it, and a factory to create the appropriate instance when needed.

Comment: Hi Max, welcome at StackOverflow. You just asked a great question. However, I think that this is primarily opinion based. Maybe you can take a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Using require and any of similiar approach is bad practice.

You should think more in OOP way how to implement this. To achieve something like this I would suggest to use interface and abstract class. In your case you need to call some APIS with different parameters on demand you should use following patterns/principles:

- [Adapter](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter/php)
- [Factory](https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-factory-design-pattern-in-php)
- [Gateway](https://medium.com/@poweredlocal/developing-a-simple-api-gateway-in-php-and-lumen-f84756cce043)
- [S.O.L.I.D](https://medium.com/prod-io/solid-principles-takeaways-ec0825a07247) - some of the principles will help you to design better what you need

Interface will look like:

```
interface ApiGateway {

   /**
    * This will execute call with optional parameters
    *
    **/
   public function call($parameters = null);
}
```

Abstract class

```
abstract class ApiGatewayAbstract implements ApiGateway
{

   /** return Adapter for handle API call **/
   abstract protected function getAdapter();
   /** return list of arguments for call */
   abstract protected function getArguments();

   public function call($parameters = null)
   {
       $adapter = $this->getAdapter();
       $arguments = $this->getArguments();

       // this will be HTTPAdapter for executing API call you need with specific params and arguments
       return $adapter->execute($arguments, $parameters);
   }
}
```

Now you can start implementing specific ApiGateways:

```
class MyApiGateway extends ApiGatewayAbstract
{
    protected $arguments = [];
    protected $adapter;

    public function __construct(HttpClientInterface $httpClient, array $arguments = [])
    {
        $this->arguments = $arguments;
        $this->adapter = $httpClient;
    }

    protected function getArguments()
    {
       return $this->arguments;
    }

    protected function getAdapter()
    {
       return $this->adapter;
    }

}
```

Final step would be Factory for your ApiGateways:

```
class ApiGatewayFactory
{
    // dynamic way to get Specific api gateway by name, or you can implement for each api gateway specific method
    public function getApiGateway($name, HttpClientInterface $adapter, array $arguments) 
    {
         $className = 'Namespace\\'.$name;
         if (!class_exist($className) {
            throw new \Exception('Unsuported ApiGateway');
         }

         // here you can use reflection or simply do:

         return new $className($adapter, $arguments);
    }
}
```

By this approach you will achieve clean way of what you want and also follow some of the principles from S.O.L.I.D. So you can add more ApiGateways with specific use cases, or different adapters ( soap, http, socket ) etc.

Hope this helps, also this is just an example have a look at the patterns and how to implement them. But this example should help you understand the approach.

Comment: What is the preferred way of getting/defining the arguments? The arguments are currently defined within the extra file, which is included.

Comment: Use configuration file and place them there, then pass them like this:

$factory = new ApiGatewayFactory();

   $gateway = $factory->getApiGateway('MyApiGateway', $config['arguments']); 
   $gateway->call();
Not sure how your architecture is solved and the exact solution, but it should be like this.